# LaTeX, fancyhdr how to add section name to header

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, fancyhdr

I am using `fancyhdr` package and unfortunately i am not able to put section name in header inside a mini page in my own defined `\pagestyle`.

For most pages i use `\pagestyle{fancy}`, but i have one page with a very long section name, so i thought i would create new `\fancypagestyle` and use `\thispagestyle` for the particular page to break text and make it a bit smaller.

This is what page with `\pagestyle{fancy}` looks like:

[image]

And this is what page with my defined `\thispagestyle{}` looks like, unfortunately it does not work for me as i dont see my section text in `\rhead`:

[image]

This is what i would like to achieve, i would also like to have the text in uppercase:

[image]

This is my defined style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./Obrazky/} }
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength\headheight{26pt}
\lhead{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{newcevro}}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Zdroje.bib}

\fancypagestyle{smallertextinheader}{ % Dokončit styl s menším textem v hlavičce
   \pagestyle{fancy}
   \fancyhf{}
   \fancyhead[LE,LO]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{newcevro}}
   \fancyhead[RE,RO]{
   \begin{minipage}[b]{8cm}
   \small{
   \uppercase{\rightmark}}
   \end{minipage}}
}
```

This is what my normal page with a short section name looks like:

```
\newpage
\pagestyle{fancy}

\section{Systémové nedostatky a návrhy na řešení}
```

This is what my page with longer section name looks like:

```
\newpage

\thispagestyle{smallertextinheader}

\section{Komparace právní úpravy svěřenského fondu s právní úpravou dědictví}
```

I do not have that much experience with LaTeX and `fancyhdr`, what could i change to achieve what i need?

Thank you

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment, i am sorry i do not entirely understand what you mean by that, i tried this: `\newpage

\thispagestyle{smallertextinheader}

\section{Komparace právní úpravy svěřenského fondu s právní úpravou dědictví}
\markright{\sectionmark{Some text}}` but it still does not work for me, is adding `\markright{\sectionmark{Some text}}` what you meant by adding \markright to every section? Thank you

Comment: I can't find it, but evidently \section does define \leftmark (not \rightmark).  Also, don't put \pagestyle(fancy} inside smallertextheader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the bottom of the image is aligned with the baseline of the text.  One can use `\raisebox` to lower the image by `\dp\strutbox` if so desired.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./Obrazky/} }
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength\headheight{26pt}
\lhead{\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=\dimexpr \headheight-\dp\strutbox]{example-image}}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Zdroje.bib}

\fancypagestyle{smallertextinheader}{ % Dokončit styl s menším textem v hlavičce
   \fancyhf{}
   \fancyhead[LE,LO]{\includegraphics[width=3cm, height=\dimexpr \headheight-\dp\strutbox]{example-image}}
   \fancyhead[RE,RO]{%
   \parbox[b]{\dimexpr \textwidth-3cm-\columnsep}%
   {\small\uppercase\leftmark}}%
}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\section{Systémové nedostatky a návrhy na řešení}
\clearpage% also flushes float queues

\thispagestyle{smallertextinheader}

\section{Komparace právní úpravy svěřenského fondu s právní úpravou dědictví}

\end{document}
```

---

Just for fun, here is a version which automatically switches if the normal title is too wide.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./Obrazky/} }
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength\headheight{26pt}
\lhead{\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=\dimexpr \headheight-\dp\strutbox]{example-image}}
\rhead{\sbox0{\textsl{\leftmark}}%
  \dimen0=\dimexpr\textwidth-3cm-\columnsep\relax
  \ifdim\wd0<\dimen0
    \usebox0
  \else
    \parbox[b]{\dimen0}{\hangindent=1.3em
      \small\textsl{\leftmark}}%
  \fi}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Zdroje.bib}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\section{Systémové nedostatky a návrhy na}

\clearpage% also flushes float queue
\section{Komparace právní úpravy svěřenského fondu s právní úpravou dědictví}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works perfectly :-) Thank you very much, i marked your answer as a solution